# Full window ui-view of openlayers map

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material, angular-openlayers

I have an angularjs app with Angular Material made with the yeoman fullstack generator.  My index.html has a navbar and a ui-view to show the sites content.

```
<!-- index.html --!>
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

The main.html page loads: `<div ng-include="'app/map/map.html'"></div>` openlayers map that I want to fill the window but it will not. The height is not always stagnate.  There is also a direct route for the map.

Setting ui-view's height to 100% doesn't work and it is not exactly what I need any way. While the map should be at 100% there are other things that load in ui-view should not. Please help me get this map to fill the window.

The map.html loads the open layers directive found [here](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive). I tried to use flex from [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) with no success either. There is obviously a way to do thais I am just new and have added height and/or flex tags to just about everything I could find in the DOM with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a full height openlayers map in a ui-view using angular material with a toolbar similar to what you need:

Be sure you have `body` and `html` set to `height: 100%;`

```
<div layout="column" style="height: 100%">
    <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
    <ui-view flex style="position:relative;"></ui-view>
</div>
```

Inside the ui-view have something like (or you can wrap your openlayers map into another element):

```
<openlayers style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%">        
</openlayers>
```

The trick is to use `position: absolute` on the `[flex]` children.

**EDIT**

I forgot that the `div` with `layout` has to be full height as well.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvetis/k3wm4tzp/3/

Comment: So, every child of ui-view set position to absolute?

Comment: I have not had success with this yet. Following your example I set everything when you set the position and the height on the openlayers tag the map disappears.

Comment: Frick I know I am close. The map needs position set on all ancestors then it doesn't disappear when you set the height but it will not fill the screen.

Comment: It appears on that column is not filling the screen and so the map just fills to where column ends?

Comment: I'll try to create a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. Here's a jsfiddle which demonstrates the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kvetis/k3wm4tzp/3/

Comment: Oh no! I just saw this.. I am sorry. Thank you so much I will be digging into this shortly!